# How to inject dependencies in a View Holder using Hilt?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I wanted to inject dependencies in a view holder. I have tried using **@EntryPoint** annotation but when using EntryPoinst.get() to get the dependency I get an error :-
*java.lang.IllegalStateException: Given component holder class java.lang.Class does not implement interface dagger.hilt.internal.GeneratedComponent or interface dagger.hilt.internal.GeneratedComponentManager at dagger.hilt.EntryPoints.get(EntryPoints.java:62)"*

```
// this is the EntryPoint interface 
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@EntryPoint
interface ProductCarouselItemViewHolderEntryPoint {
    fun analyticsSender(): AnalyticsSender
    fun getAllProductCartDetailsUseCase(): GetAllProductCartDetailsUseCase
    fun getAllMallProductCartDetailsUseCase(): GetAllMallProductCartDetailsUseCase
}
// a demo call to for a dependency
private val analyticsSender: AnalyticsSender =
    EntryPoints.get(
        SingletonComponent::class.java,
        ProductCarouselItemViewHolderEntryPoint::class.java
    )
        .analyticsSender()
```

Comment: I was battling with this today, I think that in EntryPoints.get(...) you'll want the first argument to be whatever is the container for all generated components, the applicationContext for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this but you'll need to provide the application context.

```
    // this is the EntryPoint interface 
    @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
    @EntryPoint
    interface ProductCarouselItemViewHolderEntryPoint {
        fun analyticsSender(): AnalyticsSender
        fun getAllProductCartDetailsUseCase(): GetAllProductCartDetailsUseCase
        fun getAllMallProductCartDetailsUseCase(): GetAllMallProductCartDetailsUseCase
    }

    // a demo call to for a dependency
    private val analyticsSender: AnalyticsSender =
    EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(context, 
        ProductCarouselItemViewHolderEntryPoint::class.java
    )
        .analyticsSender()
```